# Why is code launched on threadpool (via Task.Run) slower than the same code run in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, c#-5.0

I have several calculator classes that perform custom calculations. Historically methods of these classes have been launched via BackgroundWorker, because they were lengthy, run-time wise.

Recently I am converting the application to use the new async support in C# and am now running the same methods via Task.Run(), but I'm noticing they are running about 5 - 7% slower (which is a big deal in my application).

Is there an obvious/expected reason why a threadpool thread is slower than whatever BackgroundWorker was doing?

I am not making any changes to the calculation logic; I'm merely passing the calculation method to Task.Run() (and awaiting it) where before it was being supplied to the BackgroundWorker, so I'm fairly certain I haven't introduced any changes myself that account for the speed reduction.

Comment: Please post code. Could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect to see results like this if your calculations are too fine-grained.

There is an overhead to `Task.Run`: first, there's the thread pool queues that must be navigated; second, there's marshaling of the execution context (for security reasons); third, there's a wrapper around the operation that catches any exceptions.

If you use a single `BGW` with your own queue, then your queue is simpler (and likely faster). The marshaling of the execution context only happens once (for the entire `BGW`), and there's no wrappers around each operation (there's just one wrapper around `BGW.DoWork`).

Now, if you were using one `BGW` per calculation, *then* I'd expect `Task.Run` to be faster.

As an alternative, check out the Task Parallel Library. For calcuations, I recommend the `Parallel` type (or PLINQ) over `Task.Run` unless you actually need dynamic parallelism. If you want more information, read [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx), particularly [this image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff963550.666afccd-6a95-4a27-ad8f-0c06f60cc9d2%28l=en-us%29.png) (but note that "Futures" are better represented with `async`/`await` and "Pipelines" are better represented with TPL Dataflow).

Comment: I also had this suspicion. It is probably a code design error that is causing this. I hope the OP will post some code so we can know for sure.

Comment: I will try to come up with a succinct post with more details. For now, let me add these bits: 

I'm not 100% sure about what Stephen means with "too fine grained".. I assume he's asking if they are very fast methods which are getting called a lot. If so, my answer is "no".. these are single method calls like "await Task.Run(Calculator.Run())", in which the Run method may run for minutes or several days. During that operation, my app isn't doing anything else concurrently.

Comment: I have wondered from time to time if the await/async approach was the best fit for my needs (since these calcs can run a *long* time), but the syntax is so darned appealing, I didn't investigate using the TPL very much <grin>.

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett: Yes, that is what I meant. If you have a *single* method like `Run` that by itself is taking minutes, I'd be very surprised to see a 0.1% difference, let alone a 5% difference. There's definitely something going on...

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if your calculations can be run in parallel, it's easy to wrap TPL in an `async`-compatible task (you just use `Task.Run(() => Parallel.Whatever(..));`). That way you get the parallel performance ready-to-use in `async` syntax.